# how to select different expressions between xml tags with a similar character with notepad++

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have to adapt std xml for wordpress.
By exemple I've many lines like these ones :

```
line10<description>text1</description>
line18<description>text2</description>
line26<description>text3</description>
line34<description>text4</description>
line40<description>text5</description>
```

does exist a term, character to replace the text(n value) in the searchbox?
by exemple if "value"  replaces text1,text2,etc. ,
I'll use searchbox :
search `<description>"value"`
 and 
replace all by :`<content:encoded><![CDATA["value"`.

Of course, I can replace xml tags one by one (open tag first and closed tag after)but I need sometimes
to select the "text" too.
Is it clear?
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that accepting helpful answers increases the odds of others answering your future questions (and increases karma)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into using regular expressions with the search replace functionality of notepad++

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287404/using-regular-expressions-to-do-mass-replace-in-notepad-and-vim

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian:-)
after testing, that was I needed to do:
search: ^.*<description>(.*)</description>
replace by :<description></description>
<content:encoded><![CDATA[\1 ]]></content:encoded>
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[ \1]]></excerpt:encoded> 
today is only 230 changes ; sometimes it will be more than ten thousands brrrrrrrrrr! ;-)

Comment: Glad to help!  Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your issue.